# How to Pause and Resume Video Recording in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I m new to WP7 Programming,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394041(v=vs.92).aspx

this tuts working fine for me but I am looking for Pause & Resume functionality...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you posted:

```
// Pause video playback.
private void PausePlayback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Avoid duplicate taps.
    PausePlayback.IsEnabled = false;

    // If mediaElement exists, pause playback.
    if (VideoPlayer != null)
    {
        VideoPlayer.Pause();
    }

    // Set the button state and the message.
    UpdateUI(ButtonState.Paused, "Playback paused.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It is for pause/resume video player..I m looking for Video recording.I am mean pause/resume camera recording....Is it possible?